# Самоудаление php-скрипта после исполнения.

Tags: php

Что должно получиться:

1. Запускаем некий скрипт (ex:
       www.site/path/script.php).
2. Он чего-то делает.
3. После того, как отработает -
       удаляется.

Чтоб было понятнее - делаю компонент с возможностью его установки. Т.е. при первом запуске он прописывается в определенной таблице, создает другую таблицу в БД, а потом работает с ней. Не уверен, что вызывать "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS..." каждый раз - лучший вариант. 
Как еще можно сделать "установку"?

Comment: а почему скрипту просто не проверить какой-нибудь спецключик и сказать "все установлено, ничего делать не буду"?

Comment: Я когда-то делал что-то похожее по примерно такой схеме:

1. setup.php - управление различными настройками
2. install.php - одноразовые операции при первом запуске

В первом файле делал проверку: 

    if(file_exists(/path/install.php)){
        // подключаем этот файл, выполняем операции 
        // и, в случае успеха - удаляем его
    }

В этом случае, остальные операции в фале setup.php доступны не зависимо от первого запуска, а install.php отработает только один раз

Comment: Спасибо! Очень хороший вариант.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Рискну предположить, что подойдет код на подобии этого:

```
<?php
    unlink(__FILE__);
?>
```

- [`unlink`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.unlink.php)
- [`__FILE__`](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: Таки сработало. Спасибо!